# Fatal Error On Zend Project Live On Server Random

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfcuser

I have a Zend2 project running on my localhost with no problems. The app runs perfect. I Uploaded it to my server and now it gets a fatal error but not every time.

Sometimes it says this,

```
Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /home/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php on line 230

 public function getIterator()
{
    $class = $this->iteratorClass;

    return new $class($this->storage); // line 230
}
```

And sometimes it says this,

```
 File
        /vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/ArrayObject.php:184

Message:
Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead
```

Never both and sometimes it loads perfectly with no problems. The file it references is in the vendor path this is the link,

```
 public function exchangeArray($data)
    {
        if (!is_array($data) && !is_object($data)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException('Passed variable is not an array or object, using empty array instead');
        } // Line 184

        if (is_object($data) && ($data instanceof self || $data instanceof \ArrayObject)) {
            $data = $data->getArrayCopy();
        }
        if (!is_array($data)) {
            $data = (array) $data;
        }

        $storage = $this->storage;

        $this->storage = $data;

        return $storage;
    }
```

Any ideas why this would happen on a live server with a zend site but not on a localhost?

I found this post on github which I think it related to ZFCUser
[Git Hub Post](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/issues/341)

Someone in the comments says this,

```
This issue is caused by the layout.phtml when there is an error. The layout needs to render but it doesn't have $this->url
```

I have no clue what he is talking about. Is anyone able to shoot me in the right direction?

Comment: I've not used ZFCUser but from the issue it might be the kind of thing that only happens on error pages (like the 404 page)?

Comment: No sir, I have seen this happen on the login page and the user page once I am logged in. I think it might only happen on the zfcuser pages. It might be related to mbstring missing from the server. I am installing it now. It is causing an error in an error log in public.